# Why is the "docker images" command so slow on CentOS 7 system?

Tags: docker, centos, centos7

The `docker images` command takes 20-30 seconds to execute on my CentOS 7 system. Is this normal? I have 106 images in our system, which I guess is a lot, but it doesn't seem like it should take that long just to get the list of images. I am using the overlay2 storage driver. Is there anything I can do to optimize things?